# nodemailer gmail, sending email to myself doesn't show the name or email of the sender from the contact form

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I have an API to send email to myself but when the user sends me an email through my website's contact form, in the gmail it shows "me" instead of the name or the email of the one from the contact form field.

`routes/mailRoutes.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const emailController = require('../controllers/emailController');

router.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
    emailController.sendEmail(req.body).then(resultFromContoller => res.send(resultFromContoller));
});

module.exports = router;
```

`controllers/emailController.js`

```
const { transporter } = require('../services/nodemailer');

module.exports.sendEmail = async (reqBody) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, subject, message } = reqBody;
        const option = {
            from: `"${name}" <${email}>`,
            to: process.env.GOOGLE_GMAIL_CLIENT_USERNAME,
            subject: subject,
            text: `${message}\n\nSubject: ${subject}\nfrom: ${name} <${email}>`
        }

        const sendEmail = await transporter.sendMail(option);
        return {success: true, message: 'Email sent successfully!'};
    }
    catch (error) {
        return {success: false, message: error.message};
    }
};
```

`services/nodemailer.js`

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.GOOGLE_GMAIL_CLIENT_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.GOOGLE_GMAIL_CLIENT_PASSWORD
    }
});

module.exports = { transporter };
```

is there any way to display the "name" and/or "email" of the user that filled up the contact form in my gmail instead of "me"?
[image]